# ExcelReaderFactory, reading first sheet

Tags: c#, excel

I am using the `ExcelDataReaderFactory` in C#, in order to read my Excel files and inserting them to a database.
Right now I am specifying `sheetname` for the sheet that I want to use.
Can I make it to be chosen as the first sheet every time?

Here is how I load the data.

```
public IExcelDataReader getExcelReader()
{
    // ExcelDataReader works with the binary Excel file, so it needs a FileStream
    // to get started. This is how we avoid dependencies on ACE or Interop:
    FileStream stream = File.Open(_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    // We return the interface, so that
    IExcelDataReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        if (_path.EndsWith(".xls"))
        {
            reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
        }
        if (_path.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
        {
            reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
        }
        return reader;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

public IEnumerable<string> getWorksheetNames()
{
    var reader = this.getExcelReader();
    var workbook = reader.AsDataSet();
    var sheets = from DataTable sheet in workbook.Tables select sheet.TableName;
    return sheets;
}

public IEnumerable<DataRow> getData(string sheet, bool firstRowIsColumnNames = false)
{
    var reader = this.getExcelReader();
    reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = firstRowIsColumnNames;
    var workSheet = reader.AsDataSet().Tables[sheet];
    var rows = from DataRow a in workSheet.Rows select a;
    return rows;
}
```

```
getData("april"); //Here I want it to be the first sheet, and not have to choose.
```

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know that library. But I think you are converting it to a `DataSet` anyway. Then the first sheet/table is:

```
DataTable firstWorkSheet = reader.AsDataSet().Tables[0];
```

Since the [indexer of `DataTableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfsd7dz4(v=vs.110).aspx) has an overload for the index not only for the name.

So the whole method is:

```
public IEnumerable<DataRow> GetFirstSheetData(bool firstRowIsColumnNames = false)
{
    var reader = this.getExcelReader();
    reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = firstRowIsColumnNames;
    return reader.AsDataSet().Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
}
```

Comment: worth mentioning that ExcelDataReader.DataSet nuget package is required for this code as well starting from v3 (AsDataSet method was moved)

Answer (score 4):

**Update for v3**

There have been some [breaking changes in the upgrade to v3](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader#important-note-when-upgrading-from-exceldatareader-2x), so here's the original code and accepted answer updated to work with v3.

```
    public IExcelDataReader getExcelReader()
    {
        return ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(_path));
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> getWorksheetNames()
    {
        var reader = this.getExcelReader();
        var workbook = reader.AsDataSet();
        var sheets = from DataTable sheet in workbook.Tables.Cast<DataTable>() select sheet.TableName;
        return sheets;
    }

    public IEnumerable<DataRow> getData(string sheet, bool firstRowIsColumnNames = false)
    {
        var reader = this.getExcelReader();
        reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
        {
            ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
            {
                UseHeaderRow = firstRowIsColumnNames
            }
        });
        var workSheet = reader.AsDataSet().Tables[sheet];
        var rows = from DataRow a in workSheet.Rows select a;
        return rows;
    }

    public IEnumerable<DataRow> GetFirstSheetData(bool firstRowIsColumnNames = false)
    {
        var reader = this.getExcelReader();
        reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
        {
            ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
            {
                UseHeaderRow = firstRowIsColumnNames
            }
        });
        return getData(getWorksheetNames().First());
    }
```

I would say that getExcelReader has been simplified to the point of redundancy.